# A question about Fourier coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Is it true that the sequences $ (A_{n})_{n \in \Bbb{N}} = (0)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} $ and $ (B_{n})_{n \in \Bbb{N}} = \left( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} $ are the Fourier coefficients of some function $ f \in {L^{2}}[- \pi,\pi] $ with respect to the basis $ \left\{ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\cos(nt),\sin(nt) \right\} $?

I’m a little confused about what this problem wants me to prove/disprove. How can I find the functions?

Comment: The FT resulted in a delta function at the origin, therefore the original function was a flat offset in the phase (sin) term.

Comment: The series is the Fourier series of a function f which is continuous everywhere except at 0. If it is the Fourier series of another function g,  then g = f almost everywhere. The question ask: Can g be square integrable?  The basis or trigonometric system cited is complete. You can appeal to the *Theorem on Parseval relation* that if  g  is square integrable, then the integral of the square of g is given by the limit of the integral of the nth partial sum of the Fourier series (as explained by Mercy). We thus arrived at a contradiction. I assumed you are not expected to prove the relation.

Answer (score 1):

If such a function exists then
$$\tag{1}
f(t)=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin(nt).
$$
But then we would have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\infty>\|f\|^2&=&\langle f,f\rangle=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{m,n}B_mB_n\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(mt)\sin(nt)\,dt=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{m,n}\pi B_mB_n\delta_{m,n}\\
&=&\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n^2=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty,
\end{eqnarray}
which is a contradiction. Thus, such a function does not exist, in other word the Fourier series (1) does not converge to an element of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: Thank you so much! One question, what is the $\delta_{m,n}$ there? And why do we need $B_m$ and $B_n$ instead of $B_n^2$?

Comment: The series converges everywhere to the sum function and is the Fourier series of the sum function f . It does converge to  f in the L<sup>1</sup> norm.  But it does not converge in the L<sup>2</sup> norm, meaning f is not square integrable.  The sum with the integrals above is the expansion before simplification.  Each of the integral in the summation is non zero (equals $\pi$) if and only if m=n,  In the subsequent summation this is replaced by $\pi$ delta function which means it is $\pi$ only if m =n and zero otherwise.

Comment: $\delta_{n,n}=1$ and $\delta_{m,n}=0$ for every $m\ne n$.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fourier transform represented by $C_n$ terms used by engineers this would more or less be equal to $i d(t)$ where $i$ is an imaginary unit and $d$ is a delta function. I conclude that the function in the coordinate domain was a flat offset with a phase factor.